# Converting characters in PHP with file

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a textbox in which user writes some sentence , I want to change each letter on the basis of critera written in a file. How can I do this, Do I  have to look in to file for each character and read character by character.?
The file looks like this

```
Lowercase:

a = а
b = Ь
c = ϲ or с 
d = ԁ
e = е
g = ɡ
h = һ
i = і
j = ј  ϳ
k =
l =
m =
n = ɴ
o = ο  о
p = р
q =
r =
s = ѕ
t = t
u = υ
v = 
w = 
y = у
z = 

Special Characters:

1 = １
2 = ２
3 = ３
4 = ４
5 = ５
6 = ６
7 = ７
8 = ８
9 = ９

! = ǃ
( = （
) = ）

" = ＂
+ = ＋
@ = ＠
? = ？

Uppercase:

A = Α
B = Β
C = Ϲ or С
D = 
E = Ε 
F = Е
G = Ԍ
H = Η Н
I =
J = Ј
K = К
L = 
M = М Μ
N = Ν
O = Ο
P = Ρ Р
Q = 
R = 
S = Ѕ
T = Τ
U =
V = 
W =
```

Any help in this regard?

Comment: downvoters please comment, I would love to correct myself

Comment: I guess ppl downvote since you just state a general programming-problem and no partial solution or tries from your side.

Comment: @DavidEverlöf I agree the only approach that in my mind is to pick each character and then look in the file one by one.. but that is not optimized. I am jsut looking for optimized way as the solution is straight forward

Comment: I assume that you want to replace all characters on the right by the characters on the left?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte exactly, and these all characters are in a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To translate `from => to` you could use [strtr](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strtr.asp).

1.) First build a translation map...

```
// read map-file into an array
$file = file("chrmap.txt");

$map = array();
```

1.1.) If you want to translate from left to right:

```
if(!empty($file))
{
  foreach($file AS $line)
  {
    if(strpos($line, "=")!==false)
    {
      $pairs = array_map("trim", explode("=", $line));
      if(($pairs[0]!=="") && ($pairs[1]!==""))
      {
        // replace with first non empty value of the right side
        $chr = trim(preg_replace('~ \S.*$~', "", $pairs[1]));
        if(($chr!=="") && ($pairs[0]!==$chr))
        {
          $map[$pairs[0]] = $chr;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1.2.) If you want to translate from right to left:

```
if(!empty($file))
{
  // extract the pairs
  foreach($file AS $line)
  {
    if(strpos($line, "=")!==false)
    {
      $pairs = array_map("trim", explode("=", $line));
      if(!empty($pairs[1]))
      {
        // where you want to replace one or multiple values right of =
        // with corresponding "keys" of the left side
        // if multiple values, they are connected by " ", " or "
        $chrs_from = preg_split('~\s+(or\s+)?~',$pairs[1]);

        if(!empty($chrs_from))
        {
          // and set from right part > to left chr
          foreach($chrs_from as $chr)
          {
            $chr = trim($chr);
            if(($chr!=="") && ($pairs[0]!==$chr))
            {
              $map[$chr] = $pairs[0];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2.) Then translate the string using the map:

```
echo strtr($str, $map);
```

Comment: @user1765876 Did you read the map-file successfully? `$file = file("yourfile.txt"); var_dump($file);`

Comment: I did $str="I am a good boy";
echo strtr($str, $map); and it returned I am good boy as it is

Comment: the map array is fine but no replacing is being done on the text

Comment: @user1765876 You want to replace from right to left as I understood? What would be your desired result then for your sample?

Comment: it is left to right, we replace the alphabet on left side of "=" to the one on right side

Comment: @user1765876 Updated, however you could've done that yourself after understanding how it works :-) If there are multiple values on the right, the 1.1. solution picks the first one after `=` as replacement.